# Why can't I define these two constructors in Java for a single class?

Tags: java, constructor, type-erasure

I am defining a constructor for a class, and I have these two definitions:

```
MyClass(Set<ClassA> setOfA) { ... }

MyClass(Set<ClassB> setOfB) { ... }
```

I get the following error:

```
MyClass(java.util.Set<ClassA>) is already defined in MyClass
    MyClass(Set<ClassB> setOfB)
```

If I specifically made one of them a HashSet instead of a Set, the code compiles. Why?

Comment: Even without going into the details of type erasure, those two method signatures are identical. The only difference between them is the letter you're using to represent the type parameter and the name of the argument. Such differences mean nothing in terms of a method signature.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear in the way I asked, but I already have `A` and `B` defined, and they are definitely different classes that don't extend each other or are in any way related. Does it still not matter?

Comment: What do you mean you have A and B defined? If A and B are classes and not type parameters, maybe you should use _ClassA_ and _ClassB_ to make it clear. If A and B are actual types (not type *parameters*), then the answers below about type erasure explain what's happening.

Comment: Okay, I edited the question. Thanks. Do you know of a good solution to this? I don't want to combine these two constructors into one and I also don't want to make one of them HashSet instead of Set.

Comment: It's pretty impossible to make suggestions without knowing what you're trying to do (and why). But...it seems like you might want to make your class generic. Try describing to us the two different constructors, what they do, and why you need them. For example, what are the two different types you want to use and what will the two constructors do with the set that is passed as an argument.

Comment: Oh, no. That's not going to work at all. Yeah, sorry, I am leaving out details and asking you abstract questions, but let me clarify. Depending on whether I am given a set of `ClassA` objects or `ClassB` objects, I do entirely different things in my constructor. It is not as if the two constructors are defined identically except for the type. One thing that I can think of doing is changing the definitions to `MyClass(ClassA a, Set<ClassA> setA)` and likewise for `ClassB`, and when I call them I just say MyClass(new ClassA(), setA) or something, but that feels very wrong.

Comment: The specific details are kind of too long to go into, but I can try to summarize it like this. `MyClass` is really `Graph` and `ClassA`'s internal structure is very graph-like, so simply extracting this information only and making a `Graph` out of it is what the first constructor accomplishes. `ClassB` on the other hand is `Vertex` which has a list of edges going out, so given a set of vertices, I can build the graph also. I suppose a method that converts a set of `ClassA` to a `Vertex` could be used to simply do the conversion and then I can just have one constructor for a set of vertices.

Comment: @user3217013 You could always try passing in a `Class` object along with the set, or a `boolean` flag, or something like that. Not a pretty solution, but it works...

Comment: Yeah, it works, but I am trying to avoid using "hacks" like that. What would be the "Java" way, so to speak?

Comment: @jahroy I saw your comment, but you deleted it. It gives the same error.

Comment: Yep... I realized it would, so I deleted it ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have

```
MyClass(Set<A> setOfA) { ... }

MyClass(Set<B> setOfB) { ... }
```

Type erasure turns them into:

```
MyClass(Set setOfA) { ... }

MyClass(Set setOfB) { ... }
```

So now they're the same, and the compiler is confused.

However, if one of them were a `HashSet`, you end up with this:

```
MyClass(Set setOfA) { ... }

MyClass(HashSet setOfB) { ... }
```

And now they're sufficiently different for the compiler to determine which to bind at compile time.

Answer (score 5):

Because of **[type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)**, the Java compiler will (according to Java docs):

> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or `Object` if the type parameters are unbounded...
> - Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
> - Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.

In other words, the Java compiler will [convert the code to](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html):

```
MyClass(Set setOfA) { ... }

MyClass(Set setOfB) { ... }
```

so both will have the same parameters. That's the cause of the error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is what is called "type erasure". Boiled down, this means that generic types don't actually exist once the code is compiled, so your two constructor signatures `MyClass(Set<A>)` and `MyClass(Set<B>)` both look like `MyClass(Set`).

The relevant description from Oracle can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html